Hair curves is thick in Cycles but not in Eevee
I was following hair asset tutorial. Setup the mesh for hair empty normally. After placing all the hair after the hair empty and tried looking at the rendered results.
Cycles give a thick strip (I didn't setup any shader at all just drag the interpolate hair curves in the problem persist even without)


Tried both strand and strip curve render mode. re-open blender. Restart PC.
How Eevee looks which seems normal...

There is a reddit thread with no answer about this problem too.
From what I gathered it seems like cycles is stuck on Strip mode. even after changing and restarting.

And what is your question? Why Cycles does that? How to fix it?

I found a workaround using hair profile geo node before the interpolate.
